# Is there a way to set one cell on one worksheet to equal one cell on another worksheet based on the value of a specific cell?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a dropdown to select the year; 2015, 2016, 2017, etc, but based on which year is selected, I want to populate cells from a specific worksheet. So for example if 2015 is selected, cell K3 in the current worksheet equals cell E12 from the 2015 worksheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit:

So far I have the following VBA code:

```
 Option Explicit
 Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Range("J2") = "2016" Then
     Range("K3") = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("2016").Range("E12")
 Else
     Range("K3") = "0"
 End If

 End Sub
```

...but keep getting this error:

```
 Run-time error '1004':

 Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed
```

...and then Excel restarts.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/12/08/excel-reference-another-sheet-workbook/

Comment: @stefan_mit_hannover I think the user may be looking to select the source cell dynamically based on a drop down.  Although, this would definitely work if the source sheet wasn’t expected to change.

Comment: If you have a limited number of sheets, you could use the method proposed by @stefan_mit_hannover in conjunction with some IF functions, used to select the correct source cell based on the value set in the drop down.

Comment: Thank you all for you help. Apologies, I should have included in the original post, I have the following code:

Option Explicit
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("J2") = "2016" Then
    Range("K3") = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("2016").Range("E12")
Else
    Range("K3") = "0"
End If

End Sub

...but keep getting this error:

Run-time error '1004':

Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

...and then Excel restarts.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69469035/edit) instead of adding hard to parse code in comments

Comment: ...and then Excel restarts - you've changed the worksheet by writing to `Range("K3")`, which causes the Change event to fire again ... and again ... and again in an infinite loop. Note that the posted answer avoids this infinite loop by using `Intersect` to check whether `J2` changed and exiting if not.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense, thank you very much for your explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Drop-Down Worksheet Change

- In the initial solution, when writing to the destination cell, the event would get re-triggered. Although it would finish with the `If Intersect...` line, I consider it as unacceptable (wrong). Study the following solution how this is avoided.
- To see (prove) the difference, you could add e.g. the line `MsgBox "Entering Change Event"` at the beginning of each code which would show that the wrong solution shows the message box twice on each change in the drop-down cell.

**Corrected and Improved**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const sAddress As String = "E12" ' Source Cell (read from)
    
    Const dddAddress As String = "J2" ' Destination Drop-Down Cell
    Const dAddress As String = "K3" ' Destination Cell (written to)
    Const dValNoWorksheet As Long = 0 ' source worksheet not found
    Const dValBlank As Long = 0 ' source cell blank i.e. [Empty],[=""],['],...)
    
    Dim dddCell As Range: Set dddCell = Range(dddAddress)
    ' This will prevent the succeeding code to run if there was no change
    ' in the drop-down cell.
    If Intersect(Target, dddCell) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' not ddd cell
    
    ' 'Me' is the worksheet containing this code, while 'Me.Parent' is
    ' its workbook which is also 'ThisWorbook'.
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Me.Parent.Worksheets(CStr(dddCell.Value))
    On Error GoTo 0 ' enable error trapping ('Err.Number = 0')
    
    ' The following line prevents triggering the event again when writing
    ' to the destination cell ('dCell').
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' Immediately after the previous line start an error-handling routine
    ' to prevent exiting the procedure with events disabled. Its flow
    ' is self-explanatory but study it carefully.
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' enable error trapping
    
    ' Now you do your thing. If something goes wrong, the error handler
    ' will make make sure that the procedure will exit only after enabling
    ' events.
    
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = Range(dAddress)
    
    If sws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet doesn't exist
        dCell.Value = dValNoWorksheet
    Else ' worksheet exists
        Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = sws.Range(sAddress)
        If Len(CStr(sCell.Value)) = 0 Then ' blank
            dCell.Value = dValBlank
        Else ' not blank
            dCell.Value = sCell.Value
        End If
    End If

SafeExit:
    ' Be careful, if an error occurs here, it will trigger an endless loop,
    ' since the error handler is still active.
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Exit Sub

ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit ' the error handler stays active('Err.Number = 0')

End Sub
```

**Wrong**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Intersect(Target, Range("J2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' not dd cell
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Me.Parent.Worksheets(CStr(Range("J2").Value))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet doesn't exist
        Range("K3").Value = 0
    Else ' worksheet exists
        If Len(CStr(ws.Range("E12").Value)) = 0 Then ' blank
            Range("K3").Value = 0
        Else ' not blank
            Range("K3").Value = ws.Range("E12").Value
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you very much!